# Remove Shortcode [...] from Blog Preview

Tags: posts, shortcode

When utilizing shortcode (plugin, etc.) near the top of the page, the plugin shortcode displays in the preview. Is there a way to hide text within brackets [text like this] from a preview on a recent posts type of page?

The following example shows the shortcode within a blog post preview:

[image: Example of Brackets within Preview]

Comment: If you don't want shotcodes in excerpt then why not to just write one?

Comment: Interesting, to manually replace the excerpt, when editing the blog post where do I go to write that? I do not have it as an option.

Comment: Thank you, that was correct. I simply needed to enable 'Screen Options > Excerpt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with PHP. Just remove part where is `get_content()` and add this:

```
<?php 
            $content=get_the_content();
            $content = preg_replace('#\[[^\]]+\]#', '',$content);
            echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        ?>
```

That is regular expression added inside content. This regex will remove all tags inside content.

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead if you don't wanna manually write excerpts every time:

```
function wpse205632_filter_excerpt( $excerpt ) {

    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $excerpt );

    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wpse205632_filter_excerpt' );
```

Just add this snippet in `functions.php` and you are good to go.

Comment: I would agree that it's better to use `strip_shortcodes()` than custom reg-exp..

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt was not showing but would do the trick. On the edit post page, accessing 'Screen Options' and selecting 'Excerpt' allows one to manually fill the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to get content as excerpt with limited amount of words, and exclude shortcodes from Visual Composer

```
<?php $content=get_the_content(); $content = preg_replace('#\[[^\]]+\]#', '',$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words($content, 20)); echo apply_filters('the_content', $content, $trimmed_content); ?
```